# How do I get a eval statement to run the numbers as floats

Tags: python, user-interface, floating-point, wxpython, eval

I have created a GUI calculator (a screen shot included) and when a button is pressed it adds text to the textctrl so that the equation is displayed to the user. when the user presses enter it takes that text and runs it usesing eval then prints using SetValue but if i run a problem in the texctrl like 5/6 it comes out as 0 how do i make that a float

```
def eenter(self,e):
    a=self.box.GetValue()
    answer=eval(a)
    ans=str(answer)
    self.box.SetValue(ans)
```

Comment: Why should he be carefull with `eval` in this case? It is a desktop program. Anyone able to type `__import__("shutil").rmtree("/")`could just as well opena  command prompt and tpe an equally destructive command there. Unless he is coding an app for a kiosk, but it seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add on the start of your program, the following line:

`from __future__ import division`

That will make divisions behave in Python 2.x as they do in Python 3.x: with automatic casting to float if integer operators would result in a decimal number.

Answer (score 5):

Place at the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import division
```

This redefines the meaning of `/` so it is always floating point division. (Integer division is `//`.)

For more information on what this means, see [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing your input to this:

```
5/6.0
```

The above will convert the result to the float type

Comment: ya I know that but I do not want to have to do that every time i need a decimal answer